# Selecting radiobutton which is available after javascript execution

Tags: javascript, automation, robotframework

My testcase is to book an appointment. The issue is, that the required radiobutton I have to select (mandatory for the form) is available through a javascript function `getTimeSlots()`

Here is webdeveloper console with the function and output
[image]

And here the webdeveloper console showing me the radiobuttons of the appointment page
[image]

In my understandig I go to the appointment page, execute the javascript and select the radiobutton and submit the form. But this does not work.

```
Book appointment
    [Tags]  appointment
    Input Text  id:foo  here is bar
    Input Text  id:bar  here is more bar
    Click Element  id:requested_date
    # Get date out of the datepicker
    ${current_date_noon} =  Get Current Date  result_format=%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00
    ${date_in_7d} =  Add Time To Date  ${current_date_noon}  7 days
    ${unixtime} =  get time  epoch  ${date_in_7d}
    ${data_format} =  Set Variable  ${unixtime}000
    Click Element    xpath=//td[@data-date="${data_format}"]

    # FIXME Here I try to select the radiobutton
    Execute Javascript  window.getTimeSlots()
    #Select Radio button  requested_time  19:00 - 19:30
    Click Element  name:requested_time
    Capture Page Screenshot  Screenshot-termin-buchen-{index}.png
    Submit Form
```

When I run the code I get the following result in the console

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Book appointment                                                      | FAIL |
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.9.49-moby x86_64)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**How can I use robotframework to select this radiobutton?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is multiple reason why this error appear. In general it means that state of DOM changed between interaction. Since SeleniumLibrary [3.3](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/SeleniumLibrary-3.3.0.rst#wait-keywords-should-not-fail-staleelementreferenceexception-1270) keywords that start with `Wait Until` do not fail because of this error. You could try to wait until element is present and only after that click it.